# How can I add a module to the module path in using the Maven Surefire plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, java-platform-module-system

I am using Maven and the `maven-surefire-plugin` (version 3.0.0).

I am developing a Java (JPMS) module (`fancythingprovider`) that supplies a service provider (`provides ThingProvider with FancyThingProvider`).

There is another module (`thinguser`) that has a class (`ThingUser`) that loads `ThingProvider`s (`uses ThingProvider`).

To test my module, I have a normal JUnit class.  It uses `ThingUser` and expects to find my `FancyThingProvider`. This works fine.

I would now like to have another module, `simplethingprovider`, be present at test time, so that `ThingUser` will "see" both `FancyThingProvider` and `SimpleThingProvider`.  I don't want `requires simplethingprovider` to be present in my `module-info.java` because, of course, my module itself doesn't actually need it.  I just want it in the module graph at test time.

I am aware that the `maven-surefire-plugin` uses a combination of `--module-path` and `--patch-module` to make it look like my `fancythingprovider` project's `src/test/java` classes are part of the module declared by its `module-info.java` in `src/main/java/module-info.java`.  I am also aware that without a `requires` statement somewhere or some other mechanism to add it to the module graph, `simplethingprovider` will not appear in the module graph, even if it is on the test classpath (part of the unnamed module).

I am reasonably familiar with the various command-line switches that `java` offers to monkey with the module graph, including `--add-reads`, `--add-modules` and the like.

So I thought that perhaps I could cause the `maven-surefire-plugin` to add the `simplethingprovider` module.

Using `argLine`, my first thought, which was dumb in hindsight, was to supply `--add-modules simplethingprovider`.  This won't work, of course, because `simplethingprovider` is not present in the module path that Surefire runs with, and it's not read by any other module.

Realizing that `simplethingprovider`'s jar file is on the test **class**path, not the module path, and therefore that it is part of the unnamed module, my second thought was to let the `thinguser` module read the unnamed module, so that it would find my `simplethingprovider`'s service providers.  Using `argLine`, I tried `--add-reads thinguser=ALL-UNNAMED` (let `thinguser` read the unnamed module).  This did not work, which still mildly surprises me.

Then I thought, oh, since `simplethingprovider` is on the classpath and not the module path, its `module-info.java` is irrelevant in this scenario, and that changes the semantics of how service providers are found. I cannot simply rely on a `provides` statement in its `module-info.java` since it is irrelevant; I have to *also* make sure there is a `/META-INF/services/ThingProvider` service provider file at the root of the jar file, containing `SimpleThingProvider`.  I made this change but my `--add-reads` still does not work.

How can I accomplish what I want to do here?

I am aware that I can set up a new Maven project with a proper `module-info.java` file (a new module) that then uses all the other modules and so on.  I am of course prepared to do that, but I want to understand why the `--add-reads` "solution" above does not work.

Comment: Another way to ask the question: given that I cannot do `--add-modules maven:coordinates:here` in my surefire `argLine`, where `maven:coordinates:here` is an automatic module, how do I get as close to that as possible?

Comment: The plugin has changed since I last used it in an advanced manner, and apparently now you can also have a `src/test/resources/module-info.java`. Obviously your JUnit tests have to be in a different package, but if you do this, Surefire uses the module path more rigorously, detecting automatic modules automatically. I'll answer my own question for posterity once I can figure out how to explain it briefly.

Comment: In theory, you just need to add `simplethingprovider.jar` to the module path - the binding (a module that `uses ThingProvider` is in the graph, add all modules that provide that as well) should do the rest. But I have no idea how to do that with the mavan surefire plugin.

Comment: Right; adding `simplethingprovider.jar` manually would be, actually, adding `~/.m2/repository/com/foo/bar/simplethingprovider/1.0.0/...etc.etc.etc.` to the module path, assuming you know where your repo is, etc. etc. etc. Luckily it turns out the `maven-surefire-plugin` has evolved to support a `module-info.java` in your `src/main/resources` and another one in `src/test/resources` and behaves differently if both are found. The solution turns out to be quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

> ..., but I want to understand why the --add-reads "solution" above does not work.

`--add-reads` is the equivalent to the `requires` clause in `module-info.java`. Adding this would be contrary to the idea of `java.util.ServiceLoader`. The basic idea of it is, that the code facilitating it is *not* aware of which providers are actually implementing the service interface and that includes `module-info.java`. The only corresponding clause on consumer's side is - as you correctly wrote - `uses <interface>`. You already have that.

> How can I accomplish what I want to do here?

What you need here is having your test implementation `SimpleThingProvider` on the **module path** (I think you also got that concept).

The `maven-surefire-plugin` version `3.0.0-M6` or newer (including `3.0.0`) adds dependencies with scope `test` automatically to the module path (it did *not* work between `3.0.0-M2` and `3.0.0-M5`).

### Simple solution

Add the Maven module containing `SimpleThingProvider` with `<scope>test</scope>` and pick a recent version (>= 3.0.0-M6, which includes 3.0.0, 3.1.0 and 3.1.2) of `maven-surefire-plugin`.

Remark: Adding an additional `<argLine>--module-path ...</argLine>` did not work for me. I think the main reason is, that it would require the Surefire plugin to detect that specific argument and merge it with it's own, which seems not to be the case.

##### It won't work in IntelliJ

IntelliJ IDEA - unlike the Surefire plugin - does not add dependencies with scope `test` to the module path (yet). This would require to manually specify `--module-path` for the IDE test run, which can get extremely cumbersome. It can be avoided by additionally putting the service implementations into `src/main/resources/META-INF/services` plus adding the option "*Do not use --module-path option*" to the test run configuration. If you do not want to have `META-INF/services` in production code, it would be sufficient to put it once into `src/test/resources` alongside the testing code.

Putting it in production code would additionally have the advantage that your service implementation(s) would work for consumers which are not Jigsaw/JMPS-aware.