# Maven JPMS without test-scoped dependencies

Tags: java, maven, java-platform-module-system

Having a maven project "Test".

This is the `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

There is a class `/src/main/java/test/Test.java` like this:

```
package test;
public class Test {
    public final static String SQL = "CALL sysdate()";
}
```

And a unit-test `/src/test/java/test/unittest/UnitTest.java` like this:

```
package test.unittest;
import java.sql.*;
import org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver;
import test.Test;

public class UnitTest {
    public void testSQL() throws SQLException {
        try (Connection c = jdbcDriver.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test", null)) {
            Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
            if (stmt.execute(Test.SQL)) {
                ResultSet result = stmt.getResultSet();
                while (result.next()) {
                    System.out.println(result.getString(1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I call `mvn install` (as you can see) the test is executed.

```
grim@main:~/workspace/Test$ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for Test:Test:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar is either LATEST or RELEASE (both of them are being deprecated) @ line 16, column 13
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------------< Test:Test >------------------------------
[INFO] Building Test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ Test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ Test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ Test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- surefire:3.0.0-M8:test (default-test) @ Test ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running test.unittest.UnitTest
2024-02-27 10:31:31
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.119 s - in test.unittest.UnitTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jar:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ Test ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- install:3.1.0:install (default-install) @ Test ---
[INFO] Installing /home/grim/workspace/Test/pom.xml to /home/grim/.m2/repository/Test/Test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing /home/grim/workspace/Test/target/Test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/grim/.m2/repository/Test/Test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.706 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-27T10:31:31+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
grim@main:~/workspace/Test$
```

That is the setup!

### Problem:

In order to use JPMS I need to mention `java.sql` in the production module `/src/main/java/module-info.java` like this:

```
module Test {
  exports test;
  requires java.sql; // <-- unittest-dependencies in production-jar
}
```

### Question

How to avoid test-dependencies in production-jar?

Comment: Its been marked as `CloseVote - Needs debugging details`. Please tell what details are required, I may be able to improve the question.

Comment: Here is a living reference for [testing in the modular world](https://sormuras.github.io/blog/2018-09-11-testing-in-the-modular-world) that could be of help.

Comment: @Naman The living example is strange, `src/main/com` is not maven but the article claims it is. No way this is living, I will not try that.

Comment: Did you check upon the [repository linked](https://github.com/sormuras/testing-in-the-modular-world) in that blog?

Answer (score -1):

You could try and separate the module definitions for your main code and your test code when using the [Java Platform Module System (JPMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System).
That would allow you to declare `requires java.sql;` only for your test module, keeping your production JAR free of test dependencies.

```bash
Test/
├── pom.xml
├── src/
│   ├── main/
│   │   ├── java/
│   │   │   └── test/
│   │   │       ├── Test.java
│   │   │       └── module-info.java  (Main module-info)
│   │   └── ...
│   └── test/
│       ├── java/
│       │   ├── test/
│       │   │   └── unittest/
│       │   │       └── UnitTest.java
│       │   └── module-info.java  (Test module-info)
│       └── ...
```

The `/src/main/java/module-info.java` should not require `java.sql` because it is not needed for the main application's modules.

```java
module Test {
    exports test;
}
```

The `/src/test/java/module-info.java` would be separate module descriptor for your test code. It requires `java.sql` because your tests use JDBC.

```java
open module test.unittest {
    requires Test;
    requires java.sql;
    requires org.hsqldb;
}
```

Make sure your `pom.xml` is set up to compile the test `module-info.java` correctly. Maven needs to know that the test code forms a separate module. That typically involves configuring the [Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) to handle the module path for both the main and test compilation phases. You might need to adjust plugin configurations to make sure your test module-info is recognized and compiled correctly.

For instance:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Your production dependencies here -->
        <!-- Example test dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version> <!-- Consider specifying a fixed version instead -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1</version> <!-- Make sure to use a version that supports JPMS -->
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release> <!-- Use release instead of source and target to make sure module-info is handled correctly -->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Reconfiguration for the test-compile phase to include the module path -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <release>11</release>
                            <testModulePath>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</testModulePath>
                            <modulePaths>
                                <modulePath>
                                    <path>${project.build.directory}</path>
                                </modulePath>
                            </modulePaths>
                            <compilerArgs>
                                <!-- Add module-info.java from test sources -->
                                <arg>--patch-module</arg>
                                <arg>Test=${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</arg>
                            </compilerArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The `<release>` tag is used instead of `<source>` and `<target>` for better handling of JPMS features.
The test compilation phase is specifically configured to recognize the test module. The `--patch-module` option is used to specify the test `module-info.java`, allowing it to augment or replace the module declaration for tests.
The test module path is adjusted to make sure the test `module-info.java` is compiled and recognized as part of the test module.

That setup should allow you to maintain separate module descriptors for your production and test code, avoiding the inclusion of test dependencies in your production artifacts.

---

Make sure the Maven Surefire Plugin, which runs your tests, is configured to support JPMS. That may involve specifying additional module path entries or adjusting the plugin's configuration to recognize your test module setup.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <!-- Existing configuration -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Existing plugins configuration -->
            <!-- Configuration for the Maven Compiler Plugin -->
            
            <!-- Configuration for the Maven Surefire Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version> <!-- Make sure compatibility with JPMS -->
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>--add-modules java.sql</argLine>
                    <argLine>--add-reads Test=java.sql</argLine>
                    <argLine>--add-exports java.sql/test=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
                    <argLine>--patch-module Test=${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

As noted by the [OP Grim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843943/grim) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78066462/maven-jpms-without-test-scoped-dependencies#comment137652161_78081496), [`<useModulePath>true</useModulePath>`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#useModulePath), which tells Surefire to use the module path instead of the classpath (essential for running tests in a modular environment) is `true` by default.

The `--add-modules`, `--add-reads`, and `--add-exports` arguments adjust the module graph for the test run, allowing the test module to access required modules and packages.
The `--patch-module` argument is used to include the test classes and resources in the module being tested. That is necessary because the test classes are not part of the original module definition.

---

Although, as seen in "[How can I add a module to the module path in using the Maven Surefire plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76175959/6309)", the Maven Surefire Plugin version 3.0.0-M6 and newer automatically adds dependencies with a test scope to the module path. That feature simplifies the inclusion of modules like `simplethingprovider` at test time without the need for explicit `requires` statements in the `module-info.java` of the main module (`fancythingprovider` in the context of the question).

Make sure the Maven Surefire Plugin is at least version 3.0.0-M6:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5</version> <!-- Or newer -->
    <configuration>
        <!-- Configuration as necessary -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you wanted to include a hypothetical module, let's call it `testsupportmodule` (another Maven project that provides additional functionality or mocks specifically for testing purposes), only at test time for the `Test` project, you could update your `pom.xml` for the `Test` project with:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Existing production dependencies -->
        
        <!-- Test-scoped dependency for the testsupportmodule -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>testsupportmodule</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin configuration -->
            
            <!-- Maven Surefire Plugin configuration -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.5</version> <!-- Ensure using a version that supports JPMS correctly -->
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Configuration specific to your testing needs, ensuring module path includes testsupportmodule -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This `pom.xml` snippet includes the `testsupportmodule` as a test-scoped dependency. This means it will be available on the classpath during the test compilation and execution phases but won't be included in the production jar file or required by the production module descriptor (`module-info.java`).
That would avoid test dependencies in the production artifact while still enabling comprehensive testing using additional modules that provide mock implementations, helpers, or other test-specific functionality.

---

From [Naman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746118/naman)'s [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78066462/maven-jpms-without-test-scoped-dependencies?noredirect=1#comment137692953_78081496) and "[Testing In The Modular World](https://sormuras.github.io/blog/2018-09-11-testing-in-the-modular-world)":

The [`--patch-module` option](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/jpms_args.html) is used to add or replace files in a module, which is useful when your test code needs to reside in the same package as the classes under test but in a separate source set (e.g., `src/test/java`). This approach is particularly beneficial when testing package-private classes or methods.
However, if your tests only need to access public classes and methods and are located in a different package, the need for `--patch-module` diminishes. The choice to use `--patch-module` depends on the specific access requirements of your test code to the classes under test.

Given that [`useModulePath`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#useModulePath) is `true` by default in recent versions of the Maven Surefire Plugin, Namam's suggestion to set `<useModulePath>` to `false` as a workaround would force Maven to use the classpath instead of the module path, essentially bypassing the module system for test execution. This approach can simplify testing scenarios at the cost of not fully leveraging the encapsulation benefits of JPMS during testing.

Comment: useModulePath is true by default.

Comment: Have trouble to get it work cause of CDS. Cant tell exactly why. Be patient.

Comment: 1. Is this a verified working solution @VonC? 2. Why would you need patch modules as long as the package names are different? 3. If anything, the OP can modify`<useModulePath>` to false and live with existing `test` scoped dependencies in their setup, isn't it?

Comment: @Naman 1. No. I have edited the answer to include what I have understood from your points 2 and 3. Let me know if I misinterpreted anything.

Comment: Sorry, TLDR, need simple solution.